# In-App billing: Item not found

Tags: android, in-app-billing

Yet another question about "Item not found" error.

- I've created item in the dev console.
- Product ID from my application and Google Play is the same.
- My item is published
- My item is managed by Google
- I waited 1 day since I've published my item.
- I'm using test account, not dev account.
- I'm testing on a real device.
- I'm using a signed APK that is uploaded as draft to Google Play.
- Google Play static requests are working just fine.

But there is still a "Item not found" error from Google Play.

P.S. I'm wonder, maybe problem is that my account was registered just a week ago?

Comment: @victor unfortunately no. Currently I'm not using in-app billing